# Wordpress lossing CSS on some posts

Tags: css, wordpress

i am lossing my css in some post in my site. i donot know why?
but this does not happen in all posts!.

The page I need help with: https://orhansarikaya.com/index.php/2018/03/05/ihaleakpfeto/

Comment: Help us help you and specify your issue. When did it start occuring, what is your code?

Comment: You can use Developer Console to check which CSS is being overridden, or are the CSS stripped by WordPress / some plugins.

Comment: developer console as plugin or in chrome; beside that its is not clear what is the issue #colormeg is theme that am using

Comment: `/wp-content/cache/minify/65158.css` does not have anything in it. If you are using a plugin to create cache, try to disable and enable it. If it didn't help try another cache plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this cache plugin issue, please disable all cache and minify plugin and check.

And for minify and reduce size for WordPress page  **Autoptimize**  is best plugin for that.

So uninstall all minify and cache plugin and install this plugin.

Download link here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/

Comment: by the way is autoptimize enough for cache too or i have to use a cache plugin ?

Comment: @MuhanadY yes it's also for cache

Answer (score 0):

This is permalinks issue .

you need to change permalinks

WordPress comes with a handy option to create SEO friendly URL structure called Permalinks for your site. All you have to do is go to Settings » Permalinks page and choose a URL structure.

Comment: actually it does not seem to be so. am using /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname as permalinlks and it works very fine. i started to have this issue before 3 or 4 weeks no more. very old posts are working welş

Comment: It does not have anything to do with permalink.

Comment: @MuhanadY , please disable all cache and minify plugin and check

Comment: @dheerajKumar yes its an cache issue. i did disable minify and iy started to work again. but could be the solution. i must use minify to reduce the size

Comment: @MuhanadY For Minify https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/ is best plugin. please use this

Comment: @dheerajKumar please write you solution as a new post so i can approve it. most people wont read comments as you know.

Comment: Don't post multiple answers with different approaches. Combine them into one.